# Display base 10 representation of huge hexa string?

Tags: go

Trying to find how to have this hexa string "58068906d6194c6cbda7a6df" into it's base 10 representation.

I tried with this:

```
i, err := strconv.Parse("58068906d6194c6cbda7a6df", 16, 64)
```

Obviously I'm getting this error: `parsing "58068906d6194c6cbda7a6df"; value out of range`

I also need to take the base 10 string representation and get this hexa value back after some processing. i.e.:

`base10 := "58068906d6194c6cbda7a6df" => to base 10 string
some processing
hexa := base10 => to base 16 string`

Can I use the `fmt` package to dislpay the base 10? I know that displaying the hexa of a base 10 I could use %x, but what can I do with an existing string?

Thanks for your help, for a reason I cannot understand, I'm unable to find any way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hex value is larger than `int64` can hold, so you have to use a `big.Int`

https://play.golang.org/p/OPPL43u6nB

```
i := new(big.Int)
i.SetString("58068906d6194c6cbda7a6df", 16)
fmt.Println(i)
```

To get a hex string representation from a `big.Int`, you can use the `Text` method:

```
hex := i.Text(16)
```